# Unable to insert jsp forrm data into mysql database

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, xampp

[image: Xampp tomcat mysql]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Student</title>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="process.jsp">
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="first_name">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="last_name">
            <br>
            Address :<br>
            <input type="text" name="address">
            <br>
            Phone:<br>
            <input type="text" name="phone">
            <br>
            Email Id:<br>
            <input type="text" name="email">
            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have this code in this folder C:\Users\HP\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StudentWebApplication\web
I want to insert data into the database.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE StudentTB
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name varchar(50),
last_name varchar(50),
address_name varchar(50),
phone_number varchar(50),
email varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The page is not sending the data to process.jsp after I click Submit button.

process.php code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>

<%
    String first_name = request.getParameter("first_name");
    String last_name = request.getParameter("last_name");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String phone_number = request.getParameter("phone");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb", "root", "");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "INSERT INTO `studenttb`(`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `address_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES ('" + first_name + "','" + last_name + "','" + address + "','" + phone_number + "','" + email + "')";
//INSERT INTO `studenttb`(`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `address_name`, `phone_number`, `email`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6])
        int i = st.executeUpdate(query);
        if (i > 0) {
            out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> <% request.getParameter("first_name");%></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

That process page doesn't output the parameters nor insert the data to database

```
 <h1> <% request.getParameter("first_name");%></h1>
```

What could be the problem.

This is what am getting when I view process.jsp source code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ff.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js?attr=hFPEmSO1kag_2OMKGPC3NQlGiJrbkYed39XM4FFyr5reVDOZPhhb7ORqymuxFdZ9Crmx5i3xPa-zGYwM1AHQx4Vl8ktlv7HK5USWd1OpDG8" charset="UTF-8"></script></head>
    <body>
        <h1> </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Process Page]

On the process page I can see kaspersky javascript could it be the problem? I have tried to disable it but its not working.

Comment: Hi you missed `=` near `<%=request.getParameter("first_name");%>` now see if that show any value or not.Also why specify `id` in insert query if you are not passing any value for it ?

Comment: <%= request.getParameter("first_name")%> Yes without colon. Thanks!!

Comment: Does that show any value ?

Comment: @Swati yes it does